# Spring Boot app + Kubernetes liveness/readiness checks

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I'm building a few Spring Boot microservices that are getting deployed in a Kubernetes (AKS specifically) cluster. I was planning on setting the probePaths for the ***liveness & readiness*** check to both point at the actuator health endpoint, but was wondering if that may not be the best option. My original thinking was that checking the path would be useful (at least for readiness) so that traffic wouldn't be sent to it until Spring has started up and is capable of handling requests. Since these services use a database connection, and the actuator health indicator will report status as down if it can't make a connection, will that not be such a good idea?

With liveness, I'm thinking it might start recycling the pods/containers over and over even though (in the case the DB is down) it might not fix anything.

With readiness, I'm thinking it might cause the pool of available apps to be 0 if the DB is down. The app itself will most likely not be very useful if the DB is down, but parts may still work potentially I suppose.

Is there a recommended best practice for this type of thing?

Comment: first thing I would suggest is to make the app trying to connect to database multiple times in the given interval so it will not break if there is no database initialized before...

Comment: Can you explain further? Not quite sure I understand. IIRC, Spring will exist the process on startup if it cannot create the initial connection, or do you mean once it's been running and then the DB goes down?

Comment: it's up to you. I would implement "pending DB conn" for both of cases and liveness and readiness probes together. But +1 for an interesting question I hope someone who worked with spring + k8s will explain further...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.3, [the Availability state of the application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-application-availability) (including Liveness and Readiness) is supported in the core and [can be exposed as Kubernetes Probes with Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-kubernetes-probes).

Your question is spot on and this was discussed at length in [the Spring Boot issue for the Liveness/Readiness feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19593#issuecomment-572975767).

The `/health` endpoint was never really designed to expose the application state and drive how the cloud platform treats the app instance it and routes traffic to it. It's been used that way quite a lot since Spring Boot didn't have better to offer here.

The `Liveness` should only fail when the internal state of the application is broken and we cannot recover from it. As you've underlined in your question, failing here as soon as an external system is unavailable can be dangerous: the platform might recycle all application instances depending on that external system (maybe all of them?) and cause cascading failures, since other systems might be depending on that application as well.

By default, the liveness proble will reply with "Success" unless the application itself changed that internal state.

The `Readiness` probe is really about the ability for the application to serve traffic. As you've mentioned, some health checks might show the state of essential parts of the application, some others not. Spring Boot will synchronize the Readiness state with the lifecycle of the application (the web app has started, the graceful shutdown has been requested and we shouldn't route traffic anymore, etc). There is a way to configure a "readiness" health group to contain a custom set of health checks for your particular use case.

I disagree with a few statements in the answer that received the bounty, especially because a lot changed in Spring Boot since:

1. You should not use `/actuator/health` for Liveness or Readiness probes as of Spring Boot 2.3.0.
2. With the new Spring Boot lifecycle, you should move all the long-running startup tasks as `ApplicationRunner` beans - they will be executed after Liveness is Success, but before Readiness is Success. If the application startup is still too slow for the configured probes, you should then use the StartupProbe with a longer timeout and point it to the Liveness endpoint.
3. Using the management port can be dangerous, since it's using a separate web infrastructure. For example, the probes exposed on the management port might be OK but the main connector (serving the actual traffic to clients) might be overwhelmed and cannot serve more traffic. Reusing the same server and web infrastructure for the probes can be safer in some case.

For more information about this new feature, you can read the dedicated [Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot) blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's great to hear -- I'll definitely look into this further. I didn't see it at a glance, but just to confirm, do you think that database connectivity should not be included as part of the liveness/readiness checks?

Comment: liveness: probbaly not; if the connection pool can heal itself once the connection to the database is back up, then there's no point in restarting the app over and over. For Readiness, it really depends on the app: does it have fallbacks for this database? Is this same database instance shared amongst all app instances? There's no universal answer for that.

Comment: "f the application startup is still too slow for the configured probes, you should then use the StartupProbe with a longer timeout and point it to the Liveness endpoint". 
How will it help? You said the long-running task will be executed after Liveness is Success, so pointing the StartupProbe to the Liveness endpoint will not help. The StartupProbe will succeed before the long running task even start. The official doc says "the startupProbe is not necessarily needed as the Spring Boot "readinessProbe" fails until all startup tasks are done"

Comment: "if the application startup is still too slow for the configured probes, you should then use the StartupProbe with a longer timeout and point it to the Liveness endpoint".
I think this is a valid statement only if we can't move the long-running startup tasks as ApplicationRunner beans. that being said , you also said on your blog 'If you can't make those tasks `ApplicationRunner` components, you can still publish `ReadinessStateChangedEvent` before/after those startup tasks.'. So really I don't see the use case for StartupProbe, except if the liveness probe (only) is too long at startup

Comment: it really depends on how and where the startup time is being spent. Is it in done as part of the initialization of a bean? Is it in static section of class being loaded during startup? You're right, ideally you shouldn't need the StartupProbe but things can be out of your control depending on what's taking time to initialize.

Answer (score 3):

### ReadinessProbe - is the app ready to handle requests?

Use a health check to check if the app is ready to handle new requests. This can be implemented in `/actuator/health`. Also see *StartupProbe* below.

**Under high load?**

If your app is under *high load*, it may not be able to respond on health check in time, resulting in *ReadinessProbe* to *fail*. Consider using [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to get more replicas to handle the load.

### LivenessProbe - is the app deadlocked?

If your app is in a unrecoverable state, it is best if it can terminate itself, e.g. using `java.lang.System.exit(1)`. If the app can be deadlocked, unable to proceed, consider implementing an endpoint for `LivenessProbe`, this *may* be the same as for the `ReadinessProbe`.

**Not responding to readiness in a long time**

If your app haven't responded to the *ReadinessProbe* in a long time, e.g. many minutes, something is probably wrong (unless you expect this to happen for your app), then you should probably also have `/actuator/health` as your *LivenessProbe* but with a higher `failureThreshold` and a **high** `initialDelaySeconds` (e.g. a few minutes)

### StartupProbe - better alternative on Kubernetes 1.16+

The *ReadinessProbe* is most useful during app startup, since it may need to load e.g. data before it is ready to receive requests - **but** *ReadinessProbe* is executed periodic during the pod lifecycle. *StartupProbe* [is now a better alternative](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) for slow starting apps in combination with *LivenessProbe* that is only active after *StartupProbe*. You may still need a *ReadinessProbe* to notify that the pod is ready to handle requests.

### Depending on other services

If your app depends on other services, that are *not healthy* - it is better if your **app can recover** from those situations, when the backing service is up again, e.g. reconnect. Otherwise this will be a *domino chain reaction* if you have a chain of services that does not respond on *ReadinessProbe* or *LivenessProbe* because the last app in the chain have a problem. Consider to provide *degraded* service, notify that you are not in full service, maybe some of your endpoints still works correct.

### Use Management Server Port

It is the *kubelet* on the same node that send probe requests. Consider to use a [Management Server Port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port) for probes. You don't need to expose this port to the `Service`, better to use one port for *http* and another for *management*.

### Cloud provider Load Balancer Service health check

If you are using a Cloud Provider Load Balancer, it may do health checks on your services, and you may need to configure the path it sends health checks on, e.g. [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-http) defaults to `/`. This is a health check for the *Service* not for the individual *Pod*.

Answer (score 0):

We have used Spring boot Actuator custom Health check for Liveness and Readiness check. You can have your custom logic to determine whether you are able to serve the request or not. If you are able to serve the request then keep the pod alive or else restart it. For database connection issues restart will only help if your connections are stuck and not released.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the standard /actuator/health endpoint for both liveness and readiness, and have been for close to a year now. The positive sides of this is that the application is not marked as ready for use unless all its connections are up and running. The downside is due to some cases of buggy connections, which leads to downtime/restarts.

In my mind, an application that holds no connection to its database (or other important infrastructure) is as good as useless. As it probably won't function properly, you might as well report that it is unavailable. So unless you have problems with poor connection to the database or other things, I can't really see the harm of using /actuator/health for both liveness and readiness. Also, it is a cheap way of checking whether your application is up and running, which requires very little manual work to set up.