# Liveness/Readiness set of health indicators for Spring Boot service running on top of Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka-streams, readinessprobe

How health indicators should be properly configured for Spring Boot service running on top of Kafka Streams with DB connection? We use Spring Cloud Streams and Kafka Streams binding, Spring-Data JPA, Kubernetes as a container hypervisor. We have let say 3 service replicas and 9 partitions for each topic. A typical service usually joins messages from two topics and persist data in a database and publish data back to another kafka topic.

After switching to Spring Boot 2.3.1 and changing K8s liveness/readiness endpoints to the new ones:

- /actuator/health/liveness
- /actuator/health/readiness

we discovered that by default they do not have any health indicators included.

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-kubernetes-probes-external-state):

> Actuator configures the "liveness" and "readiness" probes as Health
> Groups; this means that all the Health Groups features are available
> for them. (...) By default, Spring Boot does not add other Health
> Indicators to these groups.

I believe that this is the right approach, but I have not tested that:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include: readinessState,db,binders
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include: livenessState,ping,diskSpace
```

We try to cover the following use cases:

- rolling update: not available consumption slot (idle instance) when new replica is added
- stream has died (runtime exception has been thrown)
- DB is not available during container start up / when service is running
- broker is not available

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267765/spring-boot-app-kubernetes-liveness-readiness-checks), however I believe the current one is specifically related to Kafka services. They are different in it's nature from REST services.

**Update:**
In spring boot 2.3.1 binders health indicator checks if streams are in RUNNING or REBALANCING state for Kafka 2.5 (before only RUNNING), so I guess that rolling update case with idle instance is handled by its logic.