# Spring Actuator's Liveness, Readiness, and Health show conflict status

Tags: spring-boot, health-check

I have a java application that utilizes Spring Boot v2.7.11 and Spring v5.3.27. Its liveness and readiness probes

http://localhost:8080/myApp/actuator/health/liveness
and
http://localhost:8080/myApp/actuator/health/readiness

return

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

But the health check shows "DOWN"

http://localhost:8080/myApp/actuator/health/

returns

```
{"status":"DOWN","groups":["liveness","readiness"]}
```

Below is application.properties

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
```

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267765/spring-boot-app-kubernetes-liveness-readiness-checks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, using Spring Boot 3.1.3 version.

In our case we deactivated the readi- & liveness probes, since we have a custom health-check in place during the k8s deployment.

The following settings in the `application.yml` deactivated the probes.

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: false
      enabled: true
```